# How to get access token from GoogleCredential?

Tags: authorization, google-api, oauth-2.0, credentials, access-token

I am trying to get an access token to use the Google Play Android Developer API, and I got this far using [the Google API Java Client documentation example](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Accounts):

```
HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setServiceAccountId("...gserviceaccount.com")
    .setServiceAccountScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher")
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(keyFile)
    .build();
```

But how do I get the access token from this credential? `credential.getAccessToken()` returns `null`. Am I doing something wrong, or missing some steps?

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/a/24264696/165708 some more steps you might need to take to make everything work.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Got it. You have to call credential.refreshToken() before credential.getAccessToken(). It doesn't say this anywhere in the documentation but that's what does it.

```
credential.refreshToken();
accessToken = credential.getAccessToken();
```

Comment: Right I don't see it even in google documentation. Thanks for helping Kalina

Answer (score 6):

If you use `ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream()` to create your credential object, you may have to call the `createScoped()` method too.

```
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(KEY_FILE_PATH);
    GoogleCredentials credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(fileInputStream);
    credentials = credentials.createScoped(SCOPES);
    AccessToken accessToken = credentials.refreshAccessToken();
```

Otherwise you get the error

> java.io.IOException: Scopes not configured for service account. Scoped
>   should be specified by calling createScoped or passing scopes to
>   constructor.