# Trying to send email via Service Account getting com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-api, google-apps, gmail-api

I have a Google Apps account. I'm trying to simply send an email on behalf of a user using a Service Account.

I've scoured the internet and nothing is working and i'm nearly at a loss.

I've followed the Java guides and i still keep getting `com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized`

Why does this code snippet give me 401 Unauthorized?

```
JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                    .setServiceAccountId("something@something-something.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("path/to/file/myProject.p12"))
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(GmailScopes.all())
                    .setServiceAccountUser("user@mydomain.org")
                    .build();

Gmail gmailService = new Gmail.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("My App") // DOES IT MATTER WHAT THIS IS SET TO?
                    .build();

MimeMessage mimeMessage = createEmail("myemail@gmail.com", "user@mydomain.org", "Testing", "hey");
sendMessage(gmailService, "me", mimeMessage);
```

These methods are basically copy/paste from Googles documentation:

```
/**
     * Create a MimeMessage using the parameters provided.
     *
     * @param to email address of the receiver
     * @param from email address of the sender, the mailbox account
     * @param subject subject of the email
     * @param bodyText body text of the email
     * @return the MimeMessage to be used to send email
     * @throws MessagingException
     */
    public static MimeMessage createEmail(String to,
                                          String from,
                                          String subject,
                                          String bodyText)
            throws MessagingException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);

        email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(to));
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.setText(bodyText);
        return email;
    }

    /**
       * Send an email from the user's mailbox to its recipient.
       *
       * @param service Authorized Gmail API instance.
       * @param userId User's email address. The special value "me"
       * can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
       * @param email Email to be sent.
       * @throws MessagingException
       * @throws IOException
       */
      public static void sendMessage(Gmail service, String userId, MimeMessage email)
          throws MessagingException, IOException {
        Message message = createMessageWithEmail(email);
        System.out.println("userId = " + userId);
        message = service.users().messages().send(userId, message).execute();

        System.out.println("Message id: " + message.getId());
        System.out.println(message.toPrettyString());
      }

      /**
       * Create a Message from an email
       *
       * @param email Email to be set to raw of message
       * @return Message containing base64url encoded email.
       * @throws IOException
       * @throws MessagingException
       */
      public static Message createMessageWithEmail(MimeMessage email)
          throws MessagingException, IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        email.writeTo(baos);
        String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(baos.toByteArray());
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setRaw(encodedEmail);
        return message;
      }
```

I just get this stacktrace:

```
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:384)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.my.services.NotificationServiceTest.testGmailCredential(NotificationServiceTest.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I have my service account created and set to domain wide delegation and here's a screenshot of my Manage API client access scopes:

[image]

What am i missing that I keep get 401 Unauthorized?

Comment: does your credentials file contain all the data `oauth2` wants?

Comment: Based from this [blog](https://ikaisays.com/2013/07/19/debugging-your-google-oauth-2-0-token-when-you-get-http-401s-or-403s/), the most common cause of this error is having an expired access token. This can be also due to when the developer accidentally disabled the APIs and/or the user revokes the token. You may also check on this related [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-calendar-api/NsBUa3joEN4).

Comment: How do I know if I have an expired access token? The Gmail API is enabled. How can the user revoke the token for a service account? What user are you referring to?

Comment: set application name same as you registered in google console to get credentials.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lengthy, yet helpful phone call with Google Support, we finally tracked down that if I changed `GmailScopes.all()` to the explicit scopes below then it worked.

```
Collection<String> SCOPES 
    = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(
            Arrays.asList(
                    new String[]{
                            GmailScopes.GMAIL_COMPOSE,
                            GmailScopes.GMAIL_SEND
                    }));
```

The support guy wasn't 100% sure, but he thought that maybe since my user didn't have access to ALL the gmail scopes and I was specifying `GmailScopes.all()` that it was error'ing with 401 Unauthorized before even checking which scope I was trying to use.

Answer (score 3):

look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573635/how-to-get-access-token-from-googlecredential), seems you don't have the access token yet! add refeshToken to your code:

```
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId("something@something-something.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("path/to/file/myProject.p12"))
            .setServiceAccountScopes(GmailScopes.all())
            .setServiceAccountUser("user@mydomain.org")
            .build();

        credential.refreshToken();
```

Comment: This does not apply to Service Accounts.

Answer (score 2):

The most common error causes for when making API calls with an access token are:

- expired access token (most common)
- Developer accidentally disabled the APIs (uncommon)
- User revokes token (rare)

Sometimes, more explanation exists in the response body of a HTTP 4xx. In the Java client, for example, you should log the error, because it will assist in troubleshooting:

```
try {   
       // Make your Google API call
} catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
      GoogleJsonError error = e.getDetails();
      // Print out the message and errors
}
```

You could take your existing code and make an API call here whenever you get a HTTP 4xx and log that response. This’ll return some useful information.

If the token is invalid, you can follow this steps.

- Remove the access token from your datastore or database.
- Use the refresh token to acquire a new access token (if you are using a refresh token)
- Try to make the API call again. If it works, you’re good! If not …
- Check the access token against the tokenInfo API
- If it’s still invalid, do a full reauth

You can debug everything by folowwing [this](https://ikaisays.com/2013/07/19/debugging-your-google-oauth-2-0-token-when-you-get-http-401s-or-403s/) link. It even has a tutorial video!

Comment: This is just copy paste from a troubleshooting site. It doesn't answer the OP's specific question in any way.

Comment: There is no refresh token for a service account from my understanding.