# Google Play Android Developer API

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I'm developing an android application that is going to sell in-app products.

In the google documentation about "Google Play In-App Billing" there is a section called [Purchase Status API](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/gp-purchase-status-api.html). After reading this section what I've understood is that purchases verification should be done with the Google Play Android Developer API v1.1 in my backend server.

I've tried to understand the [Google Play Android Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/index) documentation, but I don't understand what I have to do to get an authorization token.

Please, help me!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a thread where it's explained everything. How to obtain the refresh token, how to use it to obtain a new access token, and how to use the API to query a subscription.

This is the thread where I've found the solution:

[Unable to get the subscription information from Google Play Android Developer API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115381/unable-to-get-the-subscription-information-from-google-play-android-developer-ap?rq=1)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization. This contains all the details you should need.

Basically, you login via your Google Account to the google api console, create a new project from the menu on the left and then on the list of api's on the right find the name of the api for the google play developer api and turn it on.

You will then need to follow the instruction on the web page about you create a new client.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've followed these intructions and I get the access_token. I'm not very sure how to use it and I'm not sure how to use the API with this token. Where could I find an example?

Comment: I've found a thread where it's explained everything. [Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115381/unable-to-get-the-subscription-information-from-google-play-android-developer-ap?rq=1)

Comment: What about using a service account?  I can't find any documentation at all on that.