# Https problems in OAuth 2.0 Resource Server with Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, https, oauth-2.0

I am trying to set up https for OAuth 2.0 Resource Server in Spring

All I did was to add following entries in `application.properties`

```
server.port: 8444
server.ssl.key-store: keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: mypassword
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat
```

and generate certificate with:

`keytool -genkey -alias tomcat
          -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048
           -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 3650`

And I am getting following exception when runing  app.

```
DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=111, too big
```

What is more generated key and configuration works perfectly fine in Authorization Server.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298126/generated-certificate-stops-working-when-moved-to-resources-folder

Comment: @user7294900 thanks a lot. Maven seemed to be a problem.