# Where do I use Google Play Android Developer API with a Parse Android App

Tags: android, api, parse-platform, google-play

I think I am a little confused with using the Google Play Android Developer API.

I have an Android App, built with Parse, that uses Google In-App Subscriptions.

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115381/unable-to-get-the-subscription-information-from-google-play-android-developer-ap/12710896#12710896?newreg=b2e5db8e4b2d4f78986be8ef28444898), which is great.  But, where do I actually access the API to confirm the subscription from?  Do i do it from within my App??  From Parse Cloud Code?

Any ideas?