# How do I contact the Google Play Developer API using a service account from my server?

Tags: java, android, oauth, google-api-java-client, google-play-developer-api

I'm setting up my Android application with in-app subscription, but by necessity I need to verify the subscription status on the server.  I've looked around all over for how to do this, but all I can find is obtuse OAuth solutions.  According to the Android docs:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/developer-api.html#subscriptions_api_overview

I can use a service account to authenticate and make requests.  I have (as per the recommendation from the docs) the downloaded JSON file with all of my public/private keys and secrets.  I have the service account set up and linked to my application.  From here, the docs just say "You're good to go and make requests now!", without any mention on how to do that, or what libraries are required?

I've got both

```
compile("com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.22.0")
compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-androidpublisher:v2-rev20-1.21.0')
```

But have no idea how to use them, or which one I need to use.

The best answer I've been able to find is [Unable to get the subscription information from Google Play Android Developer API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115381/unable-to-get-the-subscription-information-from-google-play-android-developer-ap?rq=1), but this guy is authenticating within his Android App, and not from a backend server (using OAuth).  I thought the point of the service account was for server-to-server connections, especially since there is no "browser" to open and authenticate a redirect URL.

Does anyone know the process to do this? Is it documented somewhere I missed?