# Access to Google Play Android Developer API

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I want to check my subscription in-app purchase from my android app using my own server. I wrote a php script, but I am getting all the time error "This developer account does not own the application". I used the same google account to create an app in the Google Play Developer Console and to create a web application in the Google APIs Console.

What can be wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966945/google-credential-this-developer-account-does-not-own-the-application

Comment: Yes, but there is no answer that work for me. I don't know what mean authorize with oauth2 my application owner. As I said I created the API project in the apis console and the app in the google play developer console with the same account. I don't know what should I do else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had wrong email address set in the setting in the Google Play Developer Console.